# Когда обособляются даты?

Tags: пунктуация, даты

Насколько я поняла из прочитанных статей, даты обособляются в предложениях по усмотрению автора, но всё-таки хочется подробнее узнать об этом. 
Почему, например, в первом предложении интуитивно хочется поставить запятые, а во втором такого желания не возникает?
1) "Однажды ночью, 20 марта 1888 года, я делал что-то".
2) " Одной ночью 20 марта 1888 года я делал что-то".

Comment: *Однажды* плохо сочетается с конкретной датой.

Answer (score 1):

**Чтобы понять эту тему** (а также все другие темы в русской пунктуации)  не придумывайте предложения сами, а берите их из художественных текстов. Если всё же хотите придумать, то опишите всю ситуацию, то есть приведите **фрагмент текста**.

Тогда решение будет ясным, а именно: вы уточняете и обособляете **добавочную информацию, если считаете ее таковой.** Но это уточнение должно соответствовать смыслу текста, а обособленный член должен **вписываться в структуру предложения** (чтобы оно легко читалось).

Обычно в вашем случае **даты вовсе не присутствуют:** http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%E4%ED%E0%E6%E4%FB%20%ED%EE%F7%FC%FE&p=6

Но вот пример, где дата указана (причем она обособлена тире как вставная конструкция, то есть оформлена как отступление от темы текста):

**Однажды ночью** — это было 20 марта 1888 года — я возвращался от пациента (Артур Конан Дойл).

Пример **без обособления:**

Спички, когда остались только спички и нечего было курить, он **одной ночью** сжег их все до одной. [Олег Павлов. Асистолия // «Знамя», 2009]

Answer (score 0):

*Однажды* и  *одной ночью* плохо сочетается с последующей конкретной датой. Приходится пользоваться вставными предложениями ("это было 20 марта 1888 года" и т. п.).

Варианты с обособлением:

**В тот день, 20 марта 1888 года, я делал что-то.**
**Сегодня, 29 ноября 2019 года, я ответил на вопрос Лизы Запорожец.**
**В понедельник, 26 ноября, я был болен.**